# Como passar mais de um parâmetro no REST DEBUGGER

Tags: delphi, delphi-10

Boa tarde..
Criei um Servidor Rest -> File -> Others -> Delphi Projects -> DataSnap Server -> DataSnap REST Application.

Na unit ServerMethods Criei uma function..:

```
Autentica_Usuario (pLogin , pSenha : String) : TJsonArray;
  Var
   login , Senha : String;
begin
   Login := pLogin;
   Senha := pSenha;
end;
```

Quando vou no RestDebuger na ABA PARAMETERS e coloco usuari1,senha1  ao depurar, o parametro pSenha esta vindo com 'usuario1,senha1' e o pSenha está vindo vazio. 
Como deve ser passado mais de um parâmetro na ABA PARAMETERS do REST DEBUGER???

Comment: Nessa aba tem botoes de Add/Edit/Delete de parametros nao?

Comment: Boa tarde @Tiago Rodrigues ... tudo certinho.. Cara ter tem.. Tentei usar e não funcionou.  Possa ser que a minha função não esteja feita CORRETAMENTE para ser usada pelos botões citados.  Mas caso a função estivesse ERRADA , quando chamo o View Broser e chamo a função, aparece DOIS campos para digitar os valores necessários (login e senha) e quando dou EXECUTAR a função funciona perfeitamente. :)

Comment: Eu sei que também já tive esse problema mas sinceramente nao me recordo como resolvi :/

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde. Resolvido do seguinte modo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**1** - Na ABA REquest coloca-se o endereço até onde esta o ServerMethod 
**2** - Na ABA PARAMETERS coloca-se o Metodo chamado mais BARRA mais PARAMETRO mais BARRA mais PARAMETRO
**Exemplo..:** Login/USUARIOx/SENHAy

**3** - O Resultado esperado aparece corretamente :)

Caso algum dos senhores tenha algo a falar, sou todo olhos. :) 
Como é a primeira vez que faço um servidor REST , creio que provavelmente deve ter uma maneira "CORRETA" de se fazer a função e de se passar os parâmetros.
Abraço a todos :)